# How to create dynamic forms of listview populated by video files?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, layout

I'm creating an application similar to the link given [here][1], but don't seems to know how to create a dynamic forms of listview that display video file name or as shown in the above image? So far online what i could find is mostly "hard-coding of strings" rather than "dynamic" coding of capturing video files...

This is what i tried so far for my codes but it seems odd to me or rather incomplete. Pardon me if i'm wrong i'm kinna new in android/java could someone guide me along?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create [List object](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and add [file name](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29) strings to it. Then you provide this list to [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) constructor. Finally, you provide your ArrayAdapter to ListView via [setAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29)

Comment: i still don't seems to understand what you describe above?  By the way could you instead give me recommendation how should i modify the codes in the link here http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-i to instead complement for video files rather than music file? Sorry if i asked so much of you or rather i'm kinna new in android/java and really need much needed help... :(